# Aws Sagemaker local mode not working when running inside VS Code dev container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-sagemaker, vscode-devcontainer

I am experiencing an issue while using SageMaker to build a machine learning model.

In Sagemaker local mode, I am facing an issue that says "python3: can't open file '/opt/ml/processing/code/processing_script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory."

Even though the file is present in the correct location, the same code works fine in the normal mode, and it works fine outside of dev container as well.

I am running my project in vscode dev container and inside the dev container I am trying out the sagemaker local mode. Please let me know what could possibly be wrong with the following code.

**Error**

```
INFO:sagemaker.local.image:docker command: docker-compose -f /tmp/tmpx5_z74cs/docker-compose.yaml up --build --abort-on-container-exit
Creating 5ktwpjv1ug-algo-1-5bua0 ... 
Creating 5ktwpjv1ug-algo-1-5bua0 ... done
Attaching to 5ktwpjv1ug-algo-1-5bua0
5ktwpjv1ug-algo-1-5bua0 | python3: can't open file '/opt/ml/processing/input/code/processing_script.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
5ktwpjv1ug-algo-1-5bua0 exited with code 2
2
Aborting on container exit...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sagemaker/local/image.py", line 166, in process
    _stream_output(process)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sagemaker/local/image.py", line 916, in _stream_output
    raise RuntimeError("Process exited with code: %s" % exit_code)
RuntimeError: Process exited with code: 2

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main2.py", line 20, in <module>
    processor.run(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sagemaker/workflow/pipeline_context.py", line 272, in wrapper
    return run_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sagemaker/processing.py", line 615, in run
    self.latest_job = ProcessingJob.start_new(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sagemaker/processing.py", line 849, in start_new
    processor.sagemaker_session.process(**process_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sagemaker/session.py", line 1024, in process
    self._intercept_create_request(process_request, submit, self.process.__name__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sagemaker/session.py", line 4813, in _intercept_create_request
    return create(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sagemaker/session.py", line 1022, in submit
    self.sagemaker_client.create_processing_job(**request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sagemaker/local/local_session.py", line 128, in create_processing_job
    processing_job.start(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sagemaker/local/entities.py", line 140, in start
    self.container.process(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sagemaker/local/image.py", line 171, in process
    raise RuntimeError(msg) from e
RuntimeError: Failed to run: ['docker-compose', '-f', '/tmp/tmpx5_z74cs/docker-compose.yaml', 'up', '--build', '--abort-on-container-exit']
```

**Code**

```py
from sagemaker.local import LocalSession
from sagemaker.processing import ProcessingInput, ProcessingOutput
from sagemaker.sklearn.processing import SKLearnProcessor

sagemaker_session = LocalSession()
sagemaker_session.config = {"local": {"local_code": True}}

role = "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/service-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-20200101T000001"

processor = SKLearnProcessor(
framework_version="0.20.0", instance_count=1, instance_type="local", role=role
)

print("Starting processing job.")
print(
"Note: if launching for the first time in local mode, container image download"
" might take a few minutes to complete."
)
processor.run(
code="processing_script.py",
inputs=[
ProcessingInput(
source='./input_data/',
destination="/opt/ml/processing/input_data/",
)
],
outputs=[
ProcessingOutput(
output_name="word_count_data", source="/opt/ml/processing/processed_data/"
)
],
arguments=["job-type", "word-count"],
)

preprocessing_job_description = processor.jobs[-1].describe()
output_config = preprocessing_job_description["ProcessingOutputConfig"]

print(output_config)

for output in output_config["Outputs"]:
if output["OutputName"] == "word_count_data":
word_count_data_file = output["S3Output"]["S3Uri"]

print("Output file is located on: {}".format(word_count_data_file))
```

I tried to use sagemaker local mode to fasten the development service, as it takes more time to spin up the container in normal mode.

The issue is occurring because i am trying to use the local mode inside the VS Code dev container, everything works fine outside the dev container or when sagemaker normal mode is used.